# Java: join with elements of non-strings

Tags: java

Lets say I have a non-string collection.
How can I join it to a single string in an effective way?

```
List <ZonedDateTime> list = new ArrayList <ZonedDateTime> ();
list.add (ZonedDateTime.now ());
list.add (ZonedDateTime.now ().minusMinutes (1));
            
String x = String.join (",", list);  // ZonedDateTime is not a String
```

Comment: `list.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(","))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Stream::map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) to map the elements of the stream to `String` using `ZonedDateTime#toString`.

If you do not want to use `Stream`, you can create a `List<String>` with the `ZonedDateTime#toString` for each element in the list and then you can pass this `List<String>` to `String#join`.

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<ZonedDateTime> list = new ArrayList<ZonedDateTime>();
        list.add(ZonedDateTime.now());
        list.add(ZonedDateTime.now().minusMinutes(1));

        String x = list.stream().map(ZonedDateTime::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
        System.out.println(x);

        // A non-Stream solution
        List<String> stringValues = new ArrayList<>();
        for (ZonedDateTime zdt : list) {
            stringValues.add(zdt.toString());
        }
        String y = String.join(",", stringValues);
        System.out.println(y);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-01-02T17:09:04.878983Z[Europe/London],2021-01-02T17:08:04.881082Z[Europe/London]
2021-01-02T17:09:04.878983Z[Europe/London],2021-01-02T17:08:04.881082Z[Europe/London]
```

Comment: Note this appears to work only when all items in the list are non-null.